# Parse badly formatted JSON to a Swift object in Xcode 6

Tags: json, swift, xcode6

I'm using Swift with some JSON from a third party web service. I've managed to get the JSON back, but its not formatted in a way that i'm used to. Here is a sample:

```
{
  "Type": "Success",
  "Results": [
    {
      "Key": "UserID",
      "Value": "40372"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "Jeff"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Age",
      "Value": "35"
    },
    {
      "Key": "IsTempPassword",
      "Value": "False"
    },
    {
      "Key": "IsUserProfileComplete",
      "Value": "True"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to parse this data into a custom swift object called "User", the problem i'm having is the value for "key" is really the key itself. Is there an efficient way I can loop through this JSON looking for "Key" getting it's value then looking up the corresponding "Value" and pairing them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to my problem, In the end I used the SwiftlyJSON library available from [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON"https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON") which makes JSON in swift much simpler. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial"http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial") is a great resource for working with JSON in Swift and SwiftlyJSON from Ray Wenderlich. Anyway, its not a particularly elegant solution but it does what I need.

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
if let resultsArray = json["Results"].arrayValue {
    for x in resultsArray {
        var keyName:String = x["Key"].stringValue!
        var KeyValue:String = x["Value"].stringValue!
        switch keyName{
        case "UserID":
            UserID = KeyValue
        case "Name":
            Name = KeyValue
        case "Age":
            Age = KeyValue
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript object has a name like "response"

```
var response = {
  "Results": [
    {
      "Key": "UserID",
      "Value": "40372"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can access the key/value pairs as such:

```
var user = {}
for (var obj in response.Results)
{
  user[response.Results[obj].Key] = response.Results[obj].Value;
}

console.log(user); // Object {UserID: "40372"}
```

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WrxTClCaYs1o4eSOzpPb?p=preview) with a working example (be sure to open your JavaScript console, no results are written to the DOM).

Comment: Did you see that the question is about the *Swift* programming language?

Comment: I didn't realize you were referring to Apple's programming-language-of-the-millisecond. I assumed *Swift* referred to some JavaScript library. I suppose I should look at tags more carefully.

Comment: Notwithstanding that the answer is JavaScript, the method is a perfectly valid solution. Instantiate an empty dictionary, then iterate over the Results array, inserting each Key:Value pair into the dictionary in turn.